# How to re-create this red glow effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am trying to re-create a glow effect as the attached example on a different image, but I've got no idea where to start.

[image: Normal image] [image: Glow effect]

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi antonlab, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where to start is [Layer effects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/layer-effects-styles.html).

Specifically add an *Outer Glow* and change the color to red. Possibly add a red *Color Overlay* and change the blending mode. Just experiment.

[image]

Comment: Well that was amazingly simple. Really easy once you know how to do it. Discovering what I can do with these blending options is like discovering fire. Thanks heaps.

Comment: And remember kids, always play with fire...... thats the saying, right?